# The "property" property of the meta tag is missing in response when getting open graph data, using jquery, cross-domain ajax and YQL

Tags: jquery, yql

I'm using jquery 1.5.1, James Padolsey Cross Domain Ajax  0.11 which uses YQL to get external sites.

this is my code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://ogp.me/",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (res) {
        console.log($(res.responseText));
 });
```

The problem is that in the responseText, all meta tags are missing the "property" property.

this is what the source code of the page looks like:

<meta property="og:title" content="Open Graph Protocol" />

this is what firebug shows the responseText value is:

<meta content="Open Graph Protocol"/>

Is this a YQL problem? Is there a better way to get open graph data from external sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YQL's `html` data table, which is being used by that cross-domain AJAX plugin, runs HTML Tidy ([info](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)) on the HTML returned from the remote server.  During this process, the `property` attributes that you are looking for are removed (likely because Tidy sees them as invalid).

Comment: I ended up creating a proxy in my site. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that's still coming across this question, you just have to add `AND compat="html5"` to your queries and you will get the `property` attributes in your results.